# Error while saving TF2 model: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to save a TF model using TF V2.2 after training:

```py
...
export_directory = Path('/tmp/export')
model.save(export_directory.as_posix(), save_format='tf')
```

But the following error is returned:

```
...
[{'class_name': 'ImportedModelLayer', 'config': {'name': 'imported_model_layer', 'trainable': False, 'dtype': 'float32', 'model_path': 'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/4', 'layer_removed': 3}}, {'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'name': 'dense1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 200, 'activation': 'relu', 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}}, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'kernel_regularizer': {'class_name': 'L1L2', 'config': {'l1': 0.0, 'l2': 0.0005000000237487257}}, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}}, {'class_name': 'Dropout', 'config': {'name': 'dropout1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'rate': 0.25, 'noise_shape': None, 'seed': None}}, {'class_name': 'AttentionLayer', 'config': {'name': 'alpha', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 512, 'bag_size': 1, 'gating': False, 'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}}, 'kernel_regularizer': {'class_name': 'L1L2', 'config': {'l1': 0.0, 'l2': 0.0005000000237487257}}}}, {'class_name': 'Multiply', 'config': {'name': 'alpha_x_features', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32'}}, {'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'name': 'sigmoid_scoring', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 11, 'activation': 'sigmoid', 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}}, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}}]
2020-11-20 11:09:54.532868: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:329] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
  File "/home/xxx/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 277, in serialize_keras_object
    for key, item in config.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
[{'class_name': 'ImportedModelLayer', 'config': {'name': 'imported_model_layer', 'trainable': False, 'dtype': 'float32', 'model_path': 'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/4', 'layer_removed': 3}}, {'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'name': 'dense1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 200, 'activation': 'relu', 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}}, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'kernel_regularizer': {'class_name': 'L1L2', 'config': {'l1': 0.0, 'l2': 0.0005000000237487257}}, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}}, {'class_name': 'Dropout', 'config': {'name': 'dropout1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'rate': 0.25, 'noise_shape': None, 'seed': None}}, {'class_name': 'AttentionLayer', 'config': {'name': 'alpha', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 512, 'bag_size': 1, 'gating': False, 'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}}, 'kernel_regularizer': {'class_name': 'L1L2', 'config': {'l1': 0.0, 'l2': 0.0005000000237487257}}}}, {'class_name': 'Multiply', 'config': {'name': 'alpha_x_features', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32'}}, {'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'name': 'sigmoid_scoring', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 11, 'activation': 'sigmoid', 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}}, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}}]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My model is rather complex, the first part being an imported model (here, the Inception feature extractor from TF hub). The model itself is defined as a class inheriting from `tensorflow.keras.models.Model`. The model importation is descibed in a layer class inheriting from `tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer`.

```py
class ImportedModelLayer(Layer):
    """
    Load a model from TensorFlow Hub or from a file
    """

    # ==================================================================================================================
    def __init__(self, model_path, trainable=False, layer_removed=0, **kwargs):
        """
        Layer instantiation

        :param model_path: str, TensorFlow hub URL or file path to a saved model
        :param trainable: bool, allow the fne tuning of the model
        :param layer_removed: int, number of layers to remove at the top of the graph, only works with TF2 saved models
        :param kwargs: other args used to compile the Keras model
        """

        super(ImportedModelLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.model_path = model_path
        self.trainable = trainable
        self.layer_removed = layer_removed
        self.imported_model = None
        self.input_built = False
        self.built = False

    # ==================================================================================================================
    def build(self, input_shape):
        """
        Layer building

        :param input_shape: 2D tensor defining the input shape
        """

        if self.model_path.find('https') == -1:
            try:
                # Try loading as a saved Keras model, then remove the classification layer if required.
                self.imported_model = load_model(self.model_path, compile=False)
                self.imported_model = Sequential(self.imported_model.layers[:-self.layer_removed])
                self.imported_model.trainable = self.trainable

            except OSError:
                print(f"Saved model not found: {self.model_path}")
                sys.exit(1)
        else:
            try:
                # Try loading from TensorFlow Hub
                self.imported_model = hub.KerasLayer(self.model_path, trainable=self.trainable)

            except hub.resolver.UnsupportedHandleError:
                print(f"Model not found: {self.model_path}")
                sys.exit(1)

        self.input_built = True
        self.built = True

    # ==================================================================================================================
    @tf.function
    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        """
        Layer execution

        :param x: Keras 2D tensor [None, h, w, c], corresponding to a batch of images
        :return: feature, 2D tensor [None, feature], corresponding to a batch of features
        """

        return self.imported_model(x)

    # ==================================================================================================================
    def get_config(self):
        """
        Get the layer configuration, i.e. the parameters used by the class constructor

        :return: A config dictionary
        """

        config = super(ImportedModelLayer, self).get_config()

        config.update({
            'model_path': self.model_path,
            'trainable': self.trainable,
            'layer_removed': self.layer_removed
        })

        return config
```

At this stage, I can formulate the following observations:

- the dictionary object expected by TF is wrapped in a list.
- when I don't use `ImportedModelLayer`, but define a model directly in the Model class (i.e. I don't load any pre-trained model), the error does not occur.
- the error occurs when I use TF_hub, or when I load a model from a `.h5`  file.
- the error does not occur when I juste save the weights with `model.save_weights(...)
- the error occurs with TFv2.1, v2.2 or v2.3, but not v2.0`

The issue is clearly related to the model serialization. At some point, I use a mapping function it the model call function:

```py
features = tf.map_fn(self.feature_extraction, x)
```

with the mapped function being defined as:

```py
    @tf.function
    def feature_extraction(self, x):
        """
        Extract k features from a list of inputs. 
        :param x: Tensor[k, h, w, c], with k the number of images
        :return: Tensor[k, features], i.e. 1 feature vector per image instance
        """

        return self.imported_model(x)
```

Could the mapping be at the origine of this serialization issue? Could working with a sequential model instead of a Python class may help? Thanks a lot for your advices

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming from an mistake in the `get_config()` method in the model class. The method was returning a list instead of a dict.